# Why does integration of a radical times HeavisideTheta give a conditional expression?

Tags: symbolic, distributions

If I want to compute an integral over `x^p HeavisideTheta[y-x]` where `p` is some fraction, I do not get the desired result, but only for one particular value of `y`:

```
$Assumptions = 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 < y <= 1;
f[x_] := x^(1/2)
g[x_] := x^2
Integrate[f[x] HeavisideTheta[y - x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
Integrate[f[x] HeavisideTheta[y - x], {x, 0, y}]
Integrate[f[x] HeavisideTheta[y - x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> 0 < y < 1]
Integrate[g[x] HeavisideTheta[y - x], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

evaluates to

```
ConditionalExpression[2/3, y == 1]
(2 y^(3/2))/3
(2 y^(3/2))/3
1/3 y^3
```

while I would think the first three should give the same result.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here, or why Mathematica does not understand what I want?

I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on Windows.

Comment: I tried it on Mathematica 10.0.1 and I correctly get `(2 y^(3/2))/3` for the first three integrals (and as you probably know already, the fourth one is correct), so this seems like it could be version-specific. Can anyone else confirm this?

Comment: I get the same as OP on the same version.

Comment: Version 8 gives all results correctly without any error message or condition.

Comment: I also tried it in 8.0.4 on Linux and got the correct results. Anyone who knows what 9.0.1 does wrong and how I can fix it without updating?